# Calculating the biological standard potential

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, ph

I have an electrochemical cell with following overall reaction: 
$$\ce{5 Sn^4+ + 2 Mn^2+ + 8 H2O <=> 5 Sn^2+ + 2 MnO4- + 16 H+}$$

I have defined the half reactions as:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Sn^2+ &-> Sn^4+ + 2 e-} \\       
\ce{MnO4- + 8 H+ + 5 e- & -> Mn^2+ + 4 H2O}
\end{align}
$$

I have trouble calculating the biological standard electrochemical potential. This is what I've tried:

The standard potential can be found from tables:

$$E^\circ = \pu{1.51 V} - \pu{0.15 V} = \pu{1.36 V}$$

Then I use Nernst equation in which all species except $\ce{H+}$ are in their standard states, so their activities are all equal to $1:$

$$
\begin{align}
E &= E^\circ - \frac{RT}{vF}\ln(10)\cdot \mathrm{pH} \\
  &= \pu{1.36 V} - \frac{\pu{8.314 J mol-1 K-1} × \pu{298.15 K}}{10 × \pu{96485 C mol-1}}\ln(10) × 7 \\
  &= \pu{1.31 V},
\end{align}
$$

which is wrong. Is there something wrong with the calculations or the understanding?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108350/discussion-on-question-by-martin-calculating-the-biological-standard-potential).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the OP's Nernst equation is incorrect for several reasons. The balanced net redox equation is

$$\ce{5 Sn^{4+} (aq) + 2 Mn^{2+} (aq) + 8 H2O <=> 5 Sn^{2+} (aq) + 2 MnO4^- (aq) + 16 H+ (aq) \tag 1}$$
and n = 10 electrons for the reaction as written. The reaction quotient, Q, is

$$\ce{Q = \frac{[Sn^{2+}]^5 [MnO4^-]^2 [H+]^16}{[Sn^{4+}]^5 [Mn^{2+}]^2}              \tag 2}$$

and the Nernst equation is

$$\displaystyle{E_{cell} = E_{cell}^\circ - \frac{RT}{nF} \ln(Q) = E_{cell}^\circ - \frac{RTln(10)}{nF} \log(Q)         \tag 3}    $$

The OP's question states that "all species except $\ce{H+}$ are in their standard states, so their activities are all equal to 1". Hence, in this *very contrived* example, Q reduces dramatically:

$$\displaystyle{Q = [H^+]^{16}             \tag 4}$$

The OP notes that $\displaystyle{E_{cell}^\circ }$ = 1.36 V (from tables). With T = 298.15 K, $R = \pu{8.31446261815324 J mol-1 K-1}$ and $F = \pu{96485.3321233100184 C mol-1}$, then

$$\ce{\displaystyle{ \frac{RTln(10)}{nF} \approx \frac{0.05916 \ V}{n} }        \tag 5}$$

So the Nernst equation is simply

$$\displaystyle{E_{cell} \approx 1.36 \ V - \frac{0.05916 \ V}{n} \log(Q) = 1.36 \ V - \frac{0.05916 \ V}{10} \log([H^+]^{16})      \tag 6}    $$

Hence, using $\ce{pH = -log[H^+] = +log(1/[H^+])}$, the Nernst equation can be expressed as

$$\displaystyle{E_{cell} \approx 1.36 \ V - 16 \times \frac{0.05916 \ V}{10} \log[H^+] =  1.36 \ V + 16 \times \frac{0.05916 \ V}{10} pH      \tag 7}    $$

If pH = 7, then $\ce{E_{cell} \approx 2.02 \ V}.$

**It is better to use expression (3) in order to avoid getting too tricky**. This is where the OP went wrong: forgetting the "16" exponent on the hydrogen ion concentration and also missing the fact that the negative sign before the pre-log correction term must be subsumed into the pH definition. In a realistic example, it will not happen that everything is in standard state except the hydrogen ion.

What about dividing the net ionic equation, i.e., equation (1), by 16? Then n = 10/16 = 5/8 and all the exponents in the Q expression also get divided by 16. This is no problem if everything is in standard state except the hydrogen ion. Otherwise, it is just facilitating making a silly mistake.

Comment: Please consider giving the green checkmark to the most helpful of the posted answers. It encourages people to put some thought and time into crafting answers that are factually correct, relevant, understandable and likely to be of benefit to those, in future, who encounter the question and accepted answer. It is a small reward for those who volunteer their considerable time, effort and experience to aid others and they might well look favorably at future questions from the same person. Thanks for considering this!